# Safely sending base64 encoded string as query parameter

Tags: swift, base64, urlencode

In my app, I need to send to a server a base64-encoded string as a query parameter, eg.

```
&data=AwGZnyx+JUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)==
```

Problem is, anything works just fine when there isn't a plus sign in my string: on the other hand, everytime there's one, the server code doesn't behave correctly.

I noticed there are escaping functions (eg. `addingPercentEncoding`) but they don't work with the plus sign.

Aside from removing all the pluses "manually" (eg. with a regex), is there anything else I can do?

At the moment anything works fine if I use:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is probably interpreting the `+` sign as a space because it is often used in query parameters as a substitute for a space. `addPercentEncoding` isn't going to help you because it only translates non ASCII characters.

You'll need to manually replace `+` with `%2B` as you are doing.

.... although

`NSString` has a version of [addPercentEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) that also takes a `CharacterSet` as a parameter. So you could create a Characterset with all the base64 characters in it except `+` using [init(charactersIn:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1780137-init) i.e.

```
let safeChars = Characterset(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789/=")
```

Comment: @3000 There is another - probably better - way, see updated answer.

Comment: My only doubt is: how can I include / and exclude +? It looks like you can add symbols, not single symbols (but of course I could be wrong)

Comment: @3000 Create the ChacaterSet with [init(charactersInString:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1780137-init)

Answer (score 2):

One good way to construct a URL is to use `URLComponents`. This should work in almost all cases, and an example is shown below:

```
let base64 = "AwGZnyx+JUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)=="
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://example.com")
components?.queryItems = [ URLQueryItem(name: "data", value: "AwGZnyx+JUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)==") ]

let url = components?.url
```

**Result:**

> https://example.com?data=AwGZnyx+JUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)%3D%3D

However, in your particular case, it seems the the server is not correctly handling the `+` and you need to work around that issue similar to what you have above. The better fix would be for the server to be changed to correctly process the URL.

```
let base64 = "AwGZnyx+JUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)=="
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://example.com")
components?.queryItems = [ URLQueryItem(name: "data", value: base64) ]

let urlString = components?.string.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

**Result:**

> https://example.com?data=AwGZnyx%252BJUi0PFJoyYSEDpgtlrxP(cut...)%3D%3D